# Kendo UI ListView sorting not working

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I have a sortable list view that does not work. When I drag and drop the items, and the Ajax calls the stored procedure to update the display order, the items just go back to their original order.

The database is being updated, so I know it's not a database issue. There are no error messages and the stored procedure returns "Success". Maybe I have the list view and sortable set up wrong?

```
var DataSource;
$("#VideoView").kendoListView({
    dataSource: {
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            read: {
                type: "Get",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "../api/Admin_Videos",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            timeout: 120000
        },
        sort: [{ field: "DisplayOrder", dir: "asc" }],
        serverSorting: true
    },
    dataBound: function () {
        $(this.items()).on("dblclick", function () {
            data = DataSource[$("div.product").index(this)];
            EditVideo(data);
        });
    },
    dataBinding: function() {
        DataSource = this.dataSource.data();
    },
    template: kendo.template($("#VideoViewTemplate").html())
});

$("#VideoView").kendoSortable({
    filter: ">div.product",
    cursor: "move",
    placeholder: function (element) {
        return element.clone().css("opacity", 0.1);
    },
    hint: function (element) {
        return element.clone().removeClass("k-state-selected");
    },
    change: function (e) {
        var items = $("#VideoView").data("kendoListView").items();
        var itemList = items.children("img");
        var newList = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            newList = newList + itemList.eq(i).attr("id") + ','
        }
        newList = newList.substring(0, newList.length - 1);

        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "../api/Admin_VideoReorder",
            datatype: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ ID: newList }),
            success: function (d) {
                // rebind data
                $("#VideoView").data("kendoListView").dataSource.read();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: when you read after dragging, is the server returning in the new order?

Comment: I fixed it this morning after about 10 minutes of looking at it. My stored procedure was lacking an order by clause. I guess I just needed to walk away from it for a couple days.